# How do I create multiple custom search groups inside "Find in Project" in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to know how I can create custom search definitions in Enterprise Architect and have them in multiple custom groups other than "My Searches" oder my AddIn name.

This is what I tried so far:

- I exported my search definitions and had a look at the resulting XML but there I cannot find any relation to a group name.
- When I add searches via `repository.AddDefinedSearches()` the defined search will appear in a custom group with the same name as the registered AddIn.

Is there a way to have multiple custom groups (without registering multiple AddIns)?

In the Sparx documentation I could not find any hints on that. Thank you for your help and replies.

[image: Find in Project Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your searches to an MDG with the *Create MDG Technology* wizard.

If you import that MDG those searches will show up in their proper group with the name of the MDG.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @geert-bellekens definitely works. However I found another way to achive the same (which works slightly easier for my addin setup).

The exptected structure of an SQL search query is defined as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootSearch>
  <Search Name="{0}" GUID="{1}" PkgGUID="-1" Type="0" LnksToObj="0" CustomSearch="1" 
    AddinAndMethodName="{3}">
    <SrchOn>
      <RootTable Filter="{2}" Type="-1">
        <TableName Display="Custom SQL Search" Name="" />
        <TableHierarchy Display="" Hierarchy="" />
      </RootTable>
    </SrchOn>
    <LnksTo />
  </Search>
</RootSearch>
```

The attribute `AddInMethodName` is actually used as the *group name* under which the search will appear (and does not have to relate to the defined AddIn name).

So we can define queries with different group names as follows:

```cs
var displayName = // arbitrary search display name;
var sql = "SELECT * FROM t_object"; // arbitrary SQL search string;
var guid = "{11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555}" // any guid;
var groupName = // arbitrary group name (without dot)
var addInSearchName = groupName + "." + displayName;

var xml = string.Format(TEMPLATE_SQL_SEARCH, displayName, guid, sql, addInSearchName);

repository.AddDefinedSearches(xml);
```

The result may then look like this (the group name *SMVSQL* is unrelated to the actual AddIn name):
[image: Search group name]

For me this method proves to be easier as I have several SQL query statements defined in a `resource.resx` and want to dynamically load them when the AddIn starts. Creating and using a *MDG Technology* file seems to be more work (though this also could be created on the fly).
Note: this does not work for *AddIn Searches* where the `AddInMethodName` must resolve to a `Type.FullName` in the assembly of the AddIn.